# Python 2.7 & emulambda

Tags: python

Just installed emulambda today, using the command:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/fugue/emulambda.git
```

and created a simple python file test.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Hello world")
```

when I try and run this with the command

```
emulambda test.lambda_handler test-event.json
```

I get the errors

```
Oops! There was a problem finding your function.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/emulambda", line 5, in <module>
    emulambda.main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/emulambda/__init__.py", line 37, in main
    lfunc = import_lambda(args.lambdapath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/emulambda/__init__.py", line 121, in import_lambda
    raise e
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'lambda_handler'
```

I'm running python 2.7.12 - can anyone suggest what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You called your module `test.py`, which is a conflict with the internal Python [regression `test` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html) when you attempt to do the following:

```
emulambda test.lambda_handler test-event.json
```

Rename your file to something else like `simon_test.py` and try it again with:

```
emulambda simon_test.lambda_handler test-event.json
```

Comment: great - obvious I guess. Suffice to say that fixed it :)